# Yii2 Convert from integer to datetime to display and save into database with integer

Tags: php, datetime, yii2, yii2-validation

I have a table with column `for_date` saved by type integer in database.
In order to show `for_date` with format DateTime, I used ActiveForm with code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'for_date')->textInput([
    'class' => 'form-control datepicker',
    'value' => $model->for_date ? date(Yii::$app->params['dateFormat'], $model->for_date) : date(Yii::$app->params['dateFormat'], time()),
    'placeholder' => 'Time'])
    ->label('Attendance Date') ?>
```

But when I create and save, Yii informed `This field must be integer`

In model file, I had 2 functions below to convert before validate, but it's still error.

```
public function beforeValidate(){
    if(!is_int($this->for_date)){
        $this->for_date = strtotime($this->for_date);
        $this->for_date = date('d/M/Y', $this->for_date);
    }
    return parent::beforeValidate();
}

public function afterFind(){
    $this->for_date = \Yii::t('app', Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($this->for_date));
    $this->for_date = date('d/M/Y', $this->for_date);
    return parent::afterFind();
}
```

How can I make it right to save into database with integer?

Comment: I would leave it as `int` in the model and use getter and setter. The error message you get comes most likely from your rule settings. So you could change your validator there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. In the Model Search (my case is `AttendanceSearch.php`), find rules function and move `for_date` from line have `integer` to below lines have `safe`

My Code:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'user_id', 'project_id', 'commit_time', 'workload_type'], 'integer'],
            [['comment', 'for_date'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code `for_date` is still in a date format after `beforeValidate` runs due to the line:

```
$this->for_date = date('d/M/Y', $this->for_date);
```

Remove this line and it should work.

You will however still have problems e.g formatting of the date or someone entering an invalid date e.g `30/02/2015`.

I would suggest creating a separate property e.g. `for_date_display` and adding a date rule for this. Then in a `beforeSave` convert this date into a timestamp and set `for_date` to this value as follows:

```
public $for_date_display;
...

public function afterFind() {
    $this->for_date_display = \Yii::t('app', Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($this->for_date))
}

public function beforeSave($insert = true) {
    $this->for_date = strtotime($this->for_date_display);
    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

Comment: Why have a function beforeSave?

Comment: Because `for_date` will not be entered/edited directly by the users. They edit `for_date_display` and this needs to be transformed for saving in the database.